# SSO. Линковать ли профили социальных сетей по email?

Tags: php, mysql

Если после авторизации в социальных сетях, провайдер вернул не пустой email, стоит ли искать email в БД, и при его наличии автоматически связывать найденный аккаунт с новым ID социального профиля? Или лучше не ориентироваться на email социальных профилей и даже если есть аккаунт с таким email, создавать новый и записывать идентификатор пользователя социалки.

Или лучше такой способ: Автоматически создавать каждый раз новую локальную учетную запись, даже если email у всех социальных сетях пользователя одинаковый. Но если перед этим пользователь в настройках профиля аккаунта вручную привяжет к аккаунту разные социальные сети (как дополнительные способы входа), если еще не было логина с этих сетей и нет аккаунта у них, то при логине он будет попадать в текущий аккаунт.

Нормальная такая практика, связывание не по email социалок (фактически даже не запрашивать email), а по их ID профиля провайдера?

Comment: Это зависит исключительно от требований вашей бизнес логики. хотите вы видеть одного и того же пользователя при входе разными способами или нет. С одной стороны это может быть удобно пользователю, ему не надо помнить каким способом он входил в последний раз, с другой стороны может быть и не удобно, может он намеренно заходил разными способами что бы у него было несколько аккаунтов...

Comment: Так что надо опираться на то, что дальше эти аккаунты за собой несут, нужно ли вам побуждать пользователей к работе всегда под одним аккаунтом или может вы считаете, что для ваших пользователей создание нескольких аккаунтов это нормальное поведение и вы как раз предполагаете и больше приветствуете такое поведение